# Can you make an argument for a function to be a random sample in R?

Tags: r

So, I'd like to test how precise is t-test for detecting a mean for various distributions. But I don't want to have to define the sampling distribution each time I run the function in the function. If I write `function(data, mju)` and then as data input rnorm(n) or any other random sample, I obviously get the same results when replicating the function, because I only have the one "data" sample, that was first inputted. To understand more clearly what I want, here is the code:

```
t_ci <- function(data,mju){
 prod(t.test(data)$conf.int - mju)
}

set.seed(NULL)
prec_t <- function(data, n, N, mju){
 sim <- replicate(N, t_ci(data, mju))
  sim[sim<0]/N
}
```

The first function checks, whether the real theoretical parameter "mju" in in the confidence interval. The second one replicates the function `t_ci` N times, to see how precise the t test confidence intervals are for selected data. I'd like to have an option to just indicate the distribution and then it would generate n-sized samples N times and calculate the precision. But as far as my code goes, it only replicates the same data over and over. Maybe there is a solution for this problem?
Also, it seems that something is wrong with the function `prec_t`, because I'd like to have a count of times the t_ci produced negative outcome and then divide by N.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider `rnorm`'?

Comment: Also `set.seed(NULL)` wont do much, the first argument to `set.seed` is the "seed", second is "kind" (with default NULL).